# How to display JSON file with Node.JS/Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm VERY new to Node.js... so this is probably going to be stupid, basic.  Here is what I am trying to do:  I want to create a Node.js app that will query my MySQL database and return a JSON file to the user.

So far I have very little :)  I have a project created with Webstorm.  I have an index.js file and an index.ejs file.  The index.js file has the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var appdata = require('../data.json');
var mysql = require('mysql');

// http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/fs.html#fs.writeFile
var fs = require('fs');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xxxxxx',
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx'
    database: 'xxxxx';
});

connection.connect();

router.get('/', function(request,response) {
    connection.query('select AProgram_UID as UID, SiteDescription as Program, IcStatus as Status from AP_Details;', function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in Query', err.message);
            return response.send(500, err.message);
        };

        return JSON.stringify(results);

        connection.end();
    });

});
```

I haven't defined what goes in the index.ejs file because I really don't know where to go from here.  I can write the JSON out to file from the code shown if I use writeFile, so I know the database part is correct.

Hopefully I explained enough... as mentioned, I'm new to Node.  I just want to do something 'real' with it and this is something I need on a project I have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `router.get` callback return the JSON back to the requester by using [`res.json`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) to properly assign the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and stringify whatever is passed to it.

Also you want to remove your `return` statements to before `connection.end()` otherwise `connection.end()` will never be called.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  connection.query('select AProgram_UID as UID, SiteDescription as Program, IcStatus as Status from AP_Details;', function (err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
          console.log('Error in Query', err.message);
          res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
      else 
        // render index view and pass in results JSON
        res.json(results);

      return connection.end()            
  });
});
```

---

#### Edit to use EJS View Engine Rendering

In order to use EJS you need to have your View Engine set to EJS and have a default Views directory setup. In your main Express server file it should look something like this before any routes

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

You'll need to change the code above from using `res.json` to use [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render). You'll also need to pass your results into the render function so the `index.ejs` can access the `results` JSON

```
res.render('index', { results: results });
```

In your `index.ejs` file you can access results using the EJS markup syntax

```
<html>
  <body>  
    <p><% results %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent!  Now - in my ejs file, how do I call and display?

Comment: Are you going to be doing an AJAX request from your EJS file to the resource at `'/'` or are you planning on rendering the EJS file after going to the `'/'` route?

Comment: The plan is that at the time of request (no need for AJAX-updating), the user would receive the JSON data.  I have no problem with it being continuously updated, but there really is no need.  So - I am assuming option #2 :)

Comment: @Andrew see comments on how to pass the data to your EJS template

Comment: ok, I had a bad routing + I had to use response.send like the following:  response.send('index', {results: JSON.stringify(results)})

Comment: The only thing remaining, I think is that (After I removed the JSON.stringify more like you had suggested anyway).... it returns it like this:  {"results": [{      .  I would prefer it return the result without the prefix telling me what it was.  NOTE:  I have an empty index.ejs except for <%results %>